# A log-normal distribution in Python

Tags: python, lognormal-distribution, scipy

I have seen several questions in stackoverflow regarding how to fit a `log-normal distribution`. Still there are two clarifications that I need known.

I have a sample data, the logarithm of which follows a normal distribution. So I can fit the data using `scipy.stats.lognorm.fit` (i.e a `log-normal distribution`)

The fit is working fine, and also gives me the standard deviation. Here is my piece of code with the results.

```
sample = np.log10(data) #taking the log10 of the data

scatter,loc,mean = stats.lognorm.fit(sample,floc=0) #Gives the paramters of the fit 

x_fit = np.linspace(sample.min(),sample.max(),100)
pdf_fitted = stats.lognorm.pdf(x_fit,scatter,loc,mean) #Gives the PDF

print "scatter for data is %s" %scatter
print "mean of data is %s" %mean
```

[image]
**THE RESULT**

```
scatter for data is 0.0157
mean for data is 14.18
```

**The stddev which I call scatter is `0.0157`, which is really low! why is this so?**

**In [THIS POST](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/url/xweb.geos.ed.ac.uk/~jsteven5/blog/lognormal_distributions.ipynb) and in [THIS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534562/scipy-lognormal-fitting) it is mentioned that the `log(mean)` is the actual mean.**

But you can see from my above code, the fit that I have obtained is using a the **`sample = log(data)`** and it also seems to fit well. However when I tried

```
sample = data #INSTEAD OF LOG(DATA)
pdf_fitted = stats.lognorm.pdf(x_fit,scatter,loc,np.log10(mean))
```

The fit does not seem to work.

**1) The fit seems to look clear, but why is the stddev really low?**

**2) I also have suggestions that I should not be using log10(data), but why, the fit seems to be fine ?**

Comment: It looks like you are trying to model the logarithms of the data as if *they themselves* were lognormal.

Comment: I have tried creating my own fitting function of the form given in [THIS WEBSITE](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/url/xweb.geos.ed.ac.uk/~jsteven5/blog/lognormal_distributions.ipynb). Which gives me an almost similar scatter and fit. But here it is mentioned that the pdf uses the `ln(data)`. As you can see, the `log10(data)` clearly follows a normal distribution. If I should not use `log(data)` how should I go about fitting this data and obtaining my standard deviation?

Comment: `fit` returns shape, location, scale [link](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit)

Comment: You stated that "the logarithm of the data should follow a normal distribution", so why are you fitting sample = np.log10(data) with a lognormal? And no, "the fit seems to be fine" is not a valid reason for you to fit a normally distributed data sample with a log-normal distribution. Maybe that is why you are getting a relatively low sigma...